# Find the volume of revolution about x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find the volume of the solid generated by revolving a circle about the x-axis.

The equation of the circle is given by $$x^2 + (y - 1)^2 = 1$$
indicating that it is centred at $(0, 1)$ with radius $1$.

I tried using the formula $V = \pi \int_{-1}^1 y^2 dx$, but the problem is that after some rearrangement, I found that $y = 1 \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$ and so there are two possible values for $y^2$, and I'm not sure how to proceed from here on. All I know is that $y = 1 + \sqrt{1-x^2}$ describes the upper half of the circle, and $y = 1 - \sqrt{1-x^2}$ describes the lower half.

Comment: Calculate the volume for the top one and subtract the volume of the lower one.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: is not the volume $\pi 1^2 (2\pi .1)?$

Comment: It should be obvious if you draw it. Using $y = 1 + \sqrt{1-x^2}$, you get too much. The part that is too much is what is under $1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}$, so you subtract that.

Comment: I drew it, but I can't visualize the solid generated. I thought that integrating the top half only gives me part of the volume, so I have to integrate and add both halves.

Answer (score 0):

If a vertical line segment in the circle is revolved about the x-axis, it generates a circular ring with

$A=\pi R^2-\pi r^2=\pi(R^2-r^2)=\pi\left((1+\sqrt{1-x^2})^2-(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})^2\right)$, so the volume is given by

$\displaystyle V=\int_{-1}^1\pi\left((1+\sqrt{1-x^2})^2-(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})^2\right)dx=\int_{-1}^14\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$.

---

Alternatively, as Abel points out, using Pappus's Theorem gives

$V=A(2\pi\rho)=(\pi\cdot1^2)(2\pi\cdot1)=2\pi^2.$